# How to install libtorrent-rasterbar 0.14.10 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, deluge

I would like to install libtorrent-rasterbar 0.14.10 on Ubuntu 12.04.

This has been suggested to me as a solution to problems using Deluge behind a VPN.

I have tried adding an older Deluge PPA but that produced broken packages. 
I also tried installing the from source, but got the following error in Terminal:

```
configure: error: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.34 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
```

This my first question here, so please go easy and thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: The error message that you got when attempting to install from source was referring to the fact that you probably did not have the (excellent) [Boost C++ libraries](http://www.boost.org/) installed on your machine.  Try running `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev` and then attempting to re-compile.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. I just need to figure out how to modify the ./configure command to direct it to my boost C++ installation and I should be there.

Comment: That will not work, as per my answer, you need to install boost 1.49 or lower.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try the package libtorrent-rasterbar6? It is available in the Ubuntu repository and it packages libtorrent-rasterbar 0.15.10 in Ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar6
```

Any reason for versions other than 0.14.10 don't work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I tried that. I am trying to downgrade the package to 0.14.10 because it may be causing problems with a VPN service I am using, see: http://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=87

Unfortunately it appears that 0.14.10 isn't in the repos, hence my trying to compile from source.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install a boost version that is 1.49 or lower.